# Setting focus to a previously selected row in IG after Page Submit

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

Here is basically how it looks:

Whenever I select one of the rows on the Interactive Grid on the left, a "Selection Change [Interactive Grid]" dynamic action triggers and loads some information on the Interactive Grid on the right side.

I can add new rows on it, and I'd like that, after I click on "Save" (not shown on the picture, but it's a bit above the "Copy" button), a dynamic action triggers on Page Load and selects the row on the left Interactive Grid that was previously focused.

[image]

I found the ".closest(selector)" function to try and attempted it, like this:

```
$(".getRowId").on('click',function()
        {
            var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
            alert(currentRow.attr('id'));
        }
                     );
```

The function that I'm using on Page Load is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(currentRow(id)).focus();    
    }
                 );
```

The function ".getRowId" is inside a "**Selection Change [Interactive Grid]**" function, so I'm wondering if that's why it doesn't work. Should I have that function on a "On Click" DA in order for it work?

Comment: When do you click in this button "Save", something more is executed? or just the process to save your interactive grid? If is only the process of your interactive grid, why are you submitting the page? The default button "Save" of the interactive grid don't submit the page and preserves selected values. Look at this page https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=150297:35 the "Save" is a default button. "Save22" is a custom button that submit the page.

Comment: This link is from a sample application. They recommend disabling this default save button and using this custom button. But as you see, the default save button works and saves changes to the two interactive grids ...

Comment: The current Save button I have submits the page to run either an Insert or Update PL/SQL Process. I'm trying to find a way to save that selected row from the left, and automatically have it selected when the page loads again after the submit. 

I'm also trying a couple of other ideas, such as using a "getSelectedRecords" function, but I just won't save these selected rows to use the "setSelectedRecords" when the page is loaded again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not quite understand why do you need to submit the page, I would try using the default button to save (insert and update) the interactive grids. This button does not submit the page and preserves the selected values.

---

If do you need to submit the page, I think your solution will look like this:

1 - Create a dynamic action on "selection change (interactive grid)"
[image]

The true action is "execute javascript code"

```
//set the static id field on your interactive grid and put the value on gridID variable
var gridID = "dept";
var ig$ = apex.region(gridID).widget();
var grid = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");
var selectedRecord = grid.getSelectedRecords();
console.log(selectedRecord);
localStorage.setItem('lastSelectedRecord', JSON.stringify(selectedRecord));
```

2 - Create a dynamic action on "page load"
[image]

The true action is "execute javascript code"

```
//set the static id field on your interactive grid and put the value on gridID variable
var gridID = "dept";
var ig$ = apex.region(gridID).widget();
var grid = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");

grid.setSelectedRecords(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lastSelectedRecord')));
```

Test here https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=150297:35 click on "Save22" button

Comment: Currently there's a process that runs whenever the "Save" button is clicked to update a table in Oracle. Right now I tried the code with both dynamic actions, though the page doesn't load. I get an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null". Would it be because the string is empty when the page loads? It wouldn't make sense though, considering that the Demo website with the Save22 button works normally.

Comment: Nevermind, it works now. I had already a "Selection Change" action that was likely taking priority and the second one (with this code) wasn't executing. Now it works like a charm!

Comment: great, maybe some code modification is needed. note that I'm using localstorage, the stored records are preserved for some time (I do not know how much). It may be necessary to add the session to the name of the item used to store the records so localStorage.getItem ('&APP_SESSION.lastSelectedRecord') the same in setItem. This will restrict the use of these saved records with localStorage only for the session that the user is in. In another session the records will not exist ...

Comment: I'm now trying to have the selected rows also remain saved when I close its Modal Dialog page. One of the files manages to keep its selected row when I close the page and enter it again, but all other files don't. They keep the selected rows after the Save and Submit, but accessing the same modal dialog again, after closing, doesn't. I'll see if adding the session to it does the trick.

Comment: If do you need to clear the last selected record, you can use this https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem . You need to understand what localstorage is... like I said, some changes are needed to a full solution, but this depends how your application works...

Comment: Hello, when I get back to the page the local storage variable is empty, so the rows are not being selected. Do you have an idea of what the problem could be ?

Comment: Thanks this is awesome. Now if I can just do the same for the current page when using paging and many rows.

Comment: Tried it with a master detail, but can't get it to work on the detail grid. Tried with Page Load, Refresh and Resource Load; but no luck