# Oracle APEX IG - Check Row Selector on Page Load Based on DB Table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is is possible to check the row selector on an Interactive Grid when the page loads / refreshes based on a list of IDs retrieved from a DB table?

I have successfully managed to populate the table by retrieving the checked values using `getSelectedRecords()`.

I want these rows to remain checked when the page is reloaded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is a method setSelectedRecords https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/520052/files/static/v56/jsdoc/grid.html#setSelectedRecords there is a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061135/setting-focus-to-a-previously-selected-row-in-ig-after-page-submit/53067652#53067652 in this case the selected records don't come from a table, but from the current selection in the page.

Comment: Thnks for the reply. Umfortunately no matter what I try I can't seem to get setSelectedRecords to work. Is there any way that I can populate a globa array with PLSQL with a list of values that I can access from apex using javascript?

Comment: Why don't work? if do you have the selected records with getSelectedRecords, only thing you need to do is set using setSelectedRecords with the value that you get with getSelectedRecords... like the example in the link above

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand why do you need to fetch these values ​​from a table, and you already have the values ​​marked with the getSelectedRecords function.
In this case your problem would be very similar to the following link.
[Setting focus to a previously selected row in IG after Page Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061135/setting-focus-to-a-previously-selected-row-in-ig-after-page-submit/53067652#53067652)

If do you need to fetch the values ​​from a table to then mark your interactive grid, then a possible solution would look like this.

1 - Create a restful service to give you the IDs of the lines you need to mark. Like 20, 30, 40 ...

2 - Create a dynamic action to take after loading the page or your interactive grid. This dynamic action should execute a javascript code

3 - Your javascript code should fetch the codes from the restful service that you created. There in that service you do the SQL query you want to return the appropriate codes.

4 - Obtain the codes of the lines that you need to mark, you can mark the lines with the code below.

```
grid.setSelectedRecords([
   grid.model.getRecord(20), 
   grid.model.getRecord(30),
   grid.model.getRecord(40)
]);
```

**This is not a complete solution, just a possible way to solve the problem as you imagine doing.**

**UPD.**
You can easily test this approach in chrome console with this code:
Instead of a restful, you can using an item. In this case, your code should look like this:

```
//put in gridID the id of your IG
var gridID = "your_id";
var ig$ = apex.region(gridID).widget();
var grid = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");

//the item "PX_ITEM" contains all the IDs separated by ","
//change "PX_ITEM" for the correct name of your item
var ids = apex.item('PX_ITEM').getValue();
var aIds = ids.split(',');

//create an array of records
var aRecords = []
for(var i = 0; i < aIds.length; i++) {
    aRecords.push(grid.model.getRecord(aIds[i]));
}

//Set the selected records for your array of records
grid.setSelectedRecords(aRecords)
```

To test this code in your application you need to create a dynamic action to execute after load your page. That action should execute a javascript code (code above). Remember to create an item to store all the ids that you need to select and change in the code above the inputs needed.
Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice. I'm a Oracle DBa by trade and don't understand Javascript and Restful Services fully. I'm going to have a play around with what you've mentioned above to see how far I get.

Comment: @jjc I updated my answer with a possibly complete solution, good luck.